# $O(2)$ is isomorphic to $SO(2)\times\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: group-theory

If have proven that $\frac{O(2)}{SO(2)}$ is isomporphic to $\mathbb Z_2$.

Does is follow from this that $O(2)$ is isomorphic to $SO(2)\times\mathbb Z_2$

Comment: Use \times not x for $\times$ in math mode.

Comment: No. $\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}_2$, but $\mathbb{Z}_4 \not = \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: $SO(2)\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ is an abelian group. $O(2)$ is not.

Comment: Something along the lines that you are thinking is the Schur–Zassenhaus theorem.